# Activity Indicator integration with Master-Detail Application

Tags: android-activity, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview, master-detail

I make an iPad Master-Detail Application in storyboard with ios5.

I make tableview with NSURL.

My question and help is that i want have the activity indicator for NSURL, so that when i click on the cell in the tableview he show the activity indicator when the page are loading and when finish the activity indicator desepear.

This is my code in the MAsterViewController:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface MasterViewController (PrivateMethods)
-(void)LocateArtistPageInSafari;
-(void)LocateArtist2PageInSafari;
-(void)LocateArtist3PageInSafari;
-(void)DeselectRow;

@end


@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;




- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_detailViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

        self.detailViewController.webView.delegate = self;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSInteger nSelectedRowIdx = indexPath.section *2 + indexPath.row;
    switch (nSelectedRowIdx)

    {


        case 0:
            [self LocateArtistPageInSafari];
                break;

        case 1:
            [self LocateArtist2PageInSafari];

            break;

        case 2:
            [self LocateArtist3PageInSafari];
            break;

    }

    //[self DeselectRow];
}

-(void)DeselectRow
{
    // Unselect the selected row if any
    NSIndexPath* selection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selection) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selection animated:YES];

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



-(void)LocateArtistPageInSafari
{
    NSURL *urlInSafari = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://interia.pl"];

    // if we have an iPAD...
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // then open page in detail view (UIWebView)
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlInSafari];

        [self.detailViewController.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

    }
}


-(void)LocateArtist2PageInSafari
{
    NSURL *urlInSafari = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://on.fb.me/nFwQj6"];
    // if we have an iPAD...
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // then open page in detail view (UIWebView)
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlInSafari];
        [self.detailViewController.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }
}


-(void)LocateArtist3PageInSafari
{
    NSURL *urlInSafari = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bit.ly/nxY8AZ"];

    // if we have an iPAD...
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // then open page in detail view (UIWebView)
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlInSafari];
        [self.detailViewController.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

    }
}

@end
```

I hope somebody can help me!!!! THanks a lot